# Why is Gnome Shell broken after update?

Tags: gnome, updates

I just install today's updates in Ubuntu 12.04, and after a restart my Gnome Shell desktop looks like Gnome 2 with two panels. See photo:

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1483214/Photos/shell-break-001.png]

None of my Gnome Shell extensions work now either. The Ubuntu Software Centre says Gnome Shell is still installed. Did the update brake Gnome Shell??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. I had to uninstall the proprietary ATI graphics card drives:

```
cd /usr/share/ati
sudo sh ./fglrx-uninstall.sh
```

Then reboot.

I then reinstalled the ATI driver and everything is working again.